# Discord Python Bot - User input

Tags: python, discord, percentage

So I want to make a discord python bot that takes user inputs.
what I want to do is count % of something.

Here is what i want to do :

[image]

I made this code before starting on the discord bot. But I don't know how to take user inputs.

```
userInputOriginalPrice = float(input("Enter the original price: "))

userInputPercentage = float(input("Enter how much percantage: "))

discount = ( userInputPercentage / 100) * userInputOriginalPrice

finalCost = userInputOriginalPrice - discount

print("You saved", discount, ". Your total is", finalCost)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with a discord api module such as discord.py?  Typically one would treat a user's message content as input.  There are already resources on this site about how to receive user messages and get their content.  Have you had any issues attempting this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the client.wait_for() method which takes event and check, so

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(commands_prefix='!')

@commands.command()
async def calculate_percentage(ctx):

    await ctx.send('Enter the original price: ')
    message_response = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
    original_price = float(message_response.content)

    await ctx.send('Enter how much percantage: ')
    message_response = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
    input_percantage = float(message_response.content)

    # Your calculations
    discount = ( input_percantage / 100) * original_price 
    finalCost = original_price - input_percantage

    await ctx.send(f"You saved {discount}. Your total is, {finalCost}")

client.run('Bot Token')
```

Comment: You confused `author` with `user` in discord objects. I also recommend adding a check to the channel. Preventing messages sent in other channels from being accepted as a reply.
`check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel==ctx.channel`

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be with the python's built in `.split()` method.

For example when the user inputs `!percentage 300 60`

```py
## this will split your message where there is a space
_, orig_price, discount = message.split(" ")
```

this would save time and make a more user friendly environment, and the code is far more readable

Answer (score 0):

I saw other people post answers that do not even work! here is the correct one but a bit complicated because discord.py ended.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['discount'])
async def percentage(ctx, *nums):
operation = " / ".join(nums)
operation = " * ".join(nums)
await ctx.send(f'Tip: (discount) / 100 * (real price) \n\n{operation} = {eval(operation)}')
```