# Is there an input taking command in Python similar in the use of the command 'await'?

Tags: python, input, async-await, discord

***Background Info***

Note: I am a Async beginner. To make things clear, this question is made specifically for discord bots, and so is the code below. As all python programmers know, the `print()` command sends out a message in the console. The `input()` command, however, sends out a message and takes an input from the console.

The python `await` command can be used like this:

```
    @client.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'My latency is: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')
```

The code above is a discord bot command. There isn't any bugs, and everything is working perfectly. So when a discord user puts in the command /ping (/ is my prefix), the bot will respond by logging its current latency.

***Question***

What I want is to make a rock paper scissors game, so I definitely need a command that will take an input. However, I don't know how to utilize the await command so it will take an input. Anyone help?

P.S. You can help by explaining the ctx part. That is what I don't get as it is from a tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: Full transparency; I'm guessing. Try `await input("...")` and see if that works.

Comment: Does this help to answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587303/discord-python-bot-user-input   For the question about the `ctx` argument I would suggest to consult the documentation here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html . There is also a special chapter about the class `Context` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context  (The argument `ctx` will be of type `Context`)